# Jquery removing head and body tags on output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code that removes all whitespaces from link tags in HTML emails. The code works well, the only issue I'm getting is that it seems to remove the contents inside of the head tag and removes the opening `<body>` and closing `</body>` tag on output. Could someone help me understand what's going on please?

JSBin [here](https://jsbin.com/tipuyigipi/1/edit?html,js,output).

My JavaScript code is below:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){

    var original = $('#replace').val();

    var output = $('<html/>').html(original);
    output.find('a').each(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        var href = self.attr('href');
        if (href) {
            self.attr('href', href.replace(/[\n\r]/g, ''));
            self.attr('href', href.replace(/\s+/g, ''));
        }
    });

    $('#result').text(output.html());

});
```

If I run the JSbin and input some HTML, the result is as follows:

**Input**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE" />
 <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
 <title>TEST</title>
 <style type="text/css">
 table td {


 </style>
 </head>
 <body yahoo="fix" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; margin: 0; min-height: 1000px; padding: 0; width: 100%; background:#ffffff;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
 <div>test</div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

**Output**

```html
    
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE">
 <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
 <title>TEST</title>
 <style type="text/css">
 table td {


 </style>
 
 
 <div>test</div>
```

As you can see the HTML tag, head tag and body tag go missing. Although all the content inside stays.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking or what expected output is. Please post all relevant code in question itself and provide expected results

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it's what you want, but it's seems to be your html selection which fail. Try

```
 var output = $(document.documentElement);
```

at the place of:

```
  var output = $('<html/>').html(original);
```

Now yout selecting all your Nodes from the doc root on the output.
Maybe I understood wrong your question

Comment: May you explain the down vote? If it's justified I'll delete the answer but please explain me why